# UI Testing - Asserting on Sorting Data (Katalon/Selenium) Java

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, ui-testing, katalon-studio

I'm about to write some automated UI tests around table sorting.

The sorting allows all columns in a table to be ordered by ascending and descending order. The columns can be a string, date time, int, etc.

Can anyone advise on a pragmatic approach to asserting the columns have been ordered as expected?

Is there an approach that doesn't rely on the data being the same for each test?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Katalon as the tool but this allows for custom scripts to be written using Selenium and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take:

1. Go to https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/tables page
2. Click the "Last Name" header on the first table in order to sort the table
3. See if it is sorted by comparing the UI values with `Collections.sort()` method

```
WebUI.openBrowser("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/tables")
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='table1']//span[contains(.,'Last Name')]")).click()

List<WebElement> tableElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#table1 tr td:nth-child(1)"));
ArrayList<String> tableValues = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i < tableElements.size(); i++){
    String str = tableElements.get(i).getText();
    tableValues.add(str);
}

ArrayList<String> referenceValues = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i < tableValues.size(); i++){
    referenceValues.add(tableValues.get(i))         
}

Collections.sort(referenceValues)

assert referenceValues.equals(tableValues)
```

Comment: Note - This is much quicker at executing than my solution above.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution using selenium with Groovy (Java). The reason for this scripting language is because my organisation use a tool called Katalon which supports custom scripting in the above.

Prerequisites

- Add ID's to each cell on the table of the column I'd like to assert. This makes selecting the elements easier. For example,

`<td id="receivedDate-1">2019-04-02 00:00</td>` and so on.

Here is my solution

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By as By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement as WebElement
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory as DriverFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil as Log

WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

int untracedPostTableRowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath('//table[@id=\'UntracedPostTable\']/tbody/tr')).size()

Log.logInfo('untracedPostTableRowCount: ' + untracedPostTableRowCount)

// Start iteration from second row to compare against the first row
for (int rowIndex = 2; rowIndex <= untracedPostTableRowCount; rowIndex++) {

//Get the UTC date from within the hidden span element
String currentRowReceivedDate = driver.findElement(By.id("receivedDate-$rowIndex-utc")).getAttribute('innerHTML');

int previousRowIndex = rowIndex - 1;
String previousRowReceivedDate = driver.findElement(By.id("receivedDate-$previousRowIndex-utc")).getAttribute('innerHTML');

// compareTo() - https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-compareto-method-example/
// compareTo method converts strings into a Unicode value for comparison
// If strings are equal, compareTo will return 0
// if first string is lexicographically greater than the second string, compareTo will return a positive int
// if first string is lexicographically small than the first string, compareTo will return a negative int
assert currentRowReceivedDate.compareTo(previousRowReceivedDate) >= 0;
}
```

reference: https://forum.katalon.com/t/testing-data-that-has-been-sorted/36785